# Cannot disable checking for web.config with ImageResizer loaded

Tags: web-config, imageresizer, httpruntime

I have set allowSubDirConfig to false and added http://imageresizing.net/docs/fcnmode . 
I am running IIS 8.5 on 2012r2 datacenter. I have a large image collection behind it connected via smb. just having the IIS attempt to look for the web.config add 9 extra reads per file which is cutting my throughput to a third of what it was and adds significant load to my san's. Has anyone seen this issue or have any suggestions on a fix.

Comment: It is possible that there are virtual folders or sub-applications pointing to the same directory. Can you verify that you've checked every application pool and app to ensure that allowSubDirConfig is off within IIS and fcnMode="Disabled" for every app, and that there are no classic IIS apps?

Comment: This is a single task site that runs under a single app pool so no real chance of a different app/pool making the call. at this point I am looking at splitting the watermarking code into a separate site and using the remotereader plugin to access the images. Though that seams excessively complex of a configuration.